# Measuring change in average for groups over time

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have a large dataset with measurements of leaf retention in a species of trees. I have many different plots. 
For each plot, measurements taken for 8 (randomly selected) trees. Measurement were taken each year over three years. 
I want to know if leaf retention is getting better or worse.

To do this, I want to see if there is a  significant difference between years. 
I am thinking of using a one way Anova with repeated measures (because the groups are not independent) to test for a difference in group means for different years. 
However, I am not sure if this is the correct test as I do not know whether to treat the groups as independent. They are repeated measurements from the same plot, but the actual trees that are measured may not be the same.

Would anyone be able to give me any suggestions or advice? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Both the trees within plots and the same plots over different years are correlated. You can model this using a hierarchical, or nested model. Within a plot, is it possible the same tree is measured more than once (e.g. year 1 and 2)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, it is possible that, within a plot, the same tree could be measured in year 1 and year 2. I am not familiar with hierarchical or nested models, could that be a form of Anova?

Comment: I should also add that the plots are located in a number of different forests so this may be another variable I need to take into account in a nested model.

Comment: In that case, using the syntax of the mixed models package `lme4`, the model would be along the lines of: `response ~ fixed_effects + (1 | forest/plot/tree)`. You may experience difficulty including the random effect for trees if the number of trees with more than one measurement is low. There are several questions on here about random effects with some levels having but a single measurement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it is really helpful.

Comment: There is one further thing, not all of the forests/plots were surveyed every year so there will be missing data for certain years. Would that be a problem for this model?

Comment: Mixed models can use restricted maximum likelihood, which can still produce valid estimates under incomplete groups. **However**, you will need to consider the nature of the missingness-generating process. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Types) has a reasonable explanation of the types of missingness.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful and your advice is much appreciated.